# CSS & HTML Square Background

Tags: html, css

Can anyone guide me, How can I create a 'almost' square background in CSS?

I want to get the brown background and have text on it with the error bullets and how to create the dotted yellow on the top right in CSS?

My working progress is here:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <div id="setBackground">
            <div id="header"> <span class="style1">This is LOGO </span>

                <hr />
                <div id="body_block">
                    <p class="intro">Introduction</p>

                    <h1> Back </h1>
                    Click Here

                    <h2> Next </h2>
                    Click Here

                    <p>More about Web Design:</p>
                    <p>• Bla bla bla... .</p>
                    <p>Contact:</p>
                    <p>• Bla bla bla...</p>
                    <div id="footer">
                        <!--hr class="footer"/-->
                        <p>&copy; Copyright 2013
                        <a href="">sample.com </a>|
                        <a href="">More Site </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@charset"UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */
 hr {
    clear:both;
    border: 0;
    height:12px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #993300;
}
.intro {
    color: #1e2a74;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#6994AF;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#footer p {
    border-top: 1px solid #83CDE1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#footer a {
    text-align:right;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: @phpNoOb, Seems like a fine question to me.  There is code showing what has been tried and everything.

Comment: @Brad can you suggest me how to get that in CSS please?

Answer (score 1):

the border radius CSS attribute can help you obtain rounded corners - specifically something like this should do the trick for the pink element containing everything else.

```
div {
    /* border-radius: Top-Left , Top-Right, Bottom-Right, Bottom-Left */
    border-radius: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
}
```

i would personally break this up into a few divs, a header and body.  put the background yellow dots with color on the top div and apply border radius to the top pieces.

then place the content other divs within the body and apply those border styles for each case.

this however is just one way to do it I am sure there are plenty of other wayas.

[more info about CSS Rounded borders here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPLDr/5/)

Your design is really poor. You don't have to nest all divs inside one another. I changed your html a bit(just rearranged your divs and added two new divs `leftDiv` and `rightDiv`)
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentContainer">
        <div id="setBackground">
            <div id="header"> <span class="style1">This is LOGO </span>

                <hr />
            </div>
            <div id="body_block">
                    <p class="intro">Introduction</p>

                   <h1> Back </h1>
                   Click Here

                   <h2> Next </h2>
                   Click Here




             </div>


            <div id="leftDiv">
                    <p>More about Web Design:</p>
                    <p>• Bla bla bla... .</p>
            </div>
            <div id="rightDiv">
                    <p>Contact:</p>
                    <p>• Bla bla bla...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                    <!--hr class="footer"/-->
                    <p>
&copy; Copyright 2013
                        <a href="">sample.com </a>|
                        <a href="">More Site </a>
                        </p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Add these rules to your CSS:

```
#leftDiv{
    clear:both;
    width:200px;
    background:brown;
    float:left;
    border-top-left-radius:25px;

}
#rightDiv{
    margin-left:20px;

    border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
     background:brown;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I will try to edit and tidy them indeed - Can you please instruct me how can I create an error sign in CSS? As in this link: http://postimg.org/image/6cyb2y2mx/

Comment: @tagalo do you mean the two arrows?

Comment: the two arrows I mean (not errors my wrong) - the red arrows (Back and Next)

Comment: @tagalo You will have to use images for that..do you have the images?

Comment: @tagalo I updated my jsfiddle with an image for the back button..it seems you are very new to html/css. Pick up a good book and learn a bit more of html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
     border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Border radius is what you want to look at: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

In your case, it would go something like this:

```
border-radius: 100px 0 100px 0; /*top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/

Answer (score 0):

Try border-radius properties

**Example 1**

> Div{border-radius:10px;}

**Example 2**

> Div{border-radius:10px 15px;}

For better information visit:-
[CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/em36e/)? You can create a "pseudo" "hr" tag with a div :P

```
//IN HTML

<div id="CUSTOM_HR_WITH_TEXT">SAMPLE TEXT // Custom "hr" tag with text.</div>

//AND IN CSS

#CUSTOM_HR_WITH_TEXT {
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border: 0;
height: auto;
width: auto;
background-color: #993300;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
```